# Is there any way to use Wronskian matrix to find out if a polynomial does not belong to an ideal?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, monomial-ideals

Today I learned something about the Wronskian matrix. Can I use it to tell if some polynomial in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ does not belong to a monomial ideal? I know if a polynomial belongs to an ideal it is a linear combination of its generators, so I tried to use this.

I tried partial derivatives in Wronskian matrix, but I could not find anything out of this.